# Repeat the fade effect in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fade slide show of content inside the carousel li.

Fade slideshow works fine first time but when it is repeating second time the slideshow div is not showing at all.

Code used

```
 var quotes = $(".inner_detail div");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();    
//Slider
    $('#news-container').vTicker({ 
        speed: 800,
        pause: 6000 * quotes.length-1,
        animation: 'fade',
        mousePause: false,
        showItems: 1
    });
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNEE/32/)**

Wait until it finish the 3 slide downs and then when it starts the first li again then the fade div is not showing.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you mix up your own implementation with a plugin. What is the aim? What do you expect to be shown?

Comment: I need to show the fade contents in each li. This is to show the list of product description in each li

Comment: @Sowmya, this plugin not adapted for this and not extensible, why did you choose it?

Comment: This is the only thing which I found suitable for my requirement

Answer (score 1):

Working DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mvNEE/39/.

Clean your html codes, no need to use ul li, just use all divs.

Coz your are already using $(".inner_detail div").

## HTML

```
<div class="editorial" id="news-container">
    <!-- This is the slide show-->
    <div class="inner_detail">
        <!--First book-->
        <div>
            <img src="http://platform-testing4.s3.amazonaws.com/amazon/books/BR_Image1.jpg">
            <h1>Thrilling, Brave, and Controversial</h1>
            <span>30 Pieces of Silver: An Extremely Controversial Historical Thriller</span> 
        </div>
        
        <!--Second book-->
        <div>
            <img src="http://platform-testing4.s3.amazonaws.com/amazon/books/BR_Image2.jpg">
            <h1>Not quite What I Expected.</h1>
            <span>The Book of Shadows : The Unofficial Charmed Companion</span> 
        </div>
        
        <!--Third book-->
        <div>
            <img src="http://platform-testing4.s3.amazonaws.com/amazon/books/BR_Image3.jpg">
            <h1>I would give it many more than five stars.</h1>
            <span>The Red Tent</span> 
        </div>
        
        <div> 2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. more info </div>
        
        <div> 3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet more info more info more info more info </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is showing everything in fade effect. But my requirement is to slide the each fade effect lis. And li is not part of the fade content, it is for sliding down